# Невозможно создать новую ветвь в git-репозитории в среде NetBeans

Tags: git, netbeans, git-branch

Нажимаю "Группа" — "Ветвь" — "Создать", при любом имени ветви пишет "Ветвь с этим именем уже существует"

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Какая операционная система? Консоль открыть можете?

Comment: может HEAD надо на что-то сменить? HEAD же у вас сейчас стоит на другой (старой) ветке?

Comment: Поправил заголовок вопроса: топикстартер знает, как создаются ветки, речь в посте идёт именно о том, что они почему-то не создаются.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже, что у вас не сделан первый коммит. 
Сделайте коммит, а затем создавайте новую ветвь.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо — после первого коммита появилась ветвь master.